# Causal Graph Generation from Joint Probability Distribution and Conditional Probability

Tags: probability-distributions, causality, causal-diagrams

I am trying to find a causal graph from this data.

```
P(Z=1) = 0.25                    P(Z=0) = 0.75
P(X=1 | Z =0) = 0.85             P(X=1 | Z = 1) = 0.65
P(Y=1 | Z =1, X =0) = 0.75       P(Y=1 | Z =1, X =1) = 0.25
P(Y=1 | Z =0, X =1) = 0. 5       P(Y=1 | Z =0, X =0) = 0. 5
```

From this data, I have calculated this:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Now I want to generate the causal graph representing this problem's causal story. Can you please help me to generate the causal graph?